# How to pass the jquery action into ejs?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs

I meet a question, there's some code on `a.ejs`

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <%=mary%>
</form>
```

and in `a.js`

```
 .get("/", async (ctx) => {
    await ctx.render("a", {
       mary:""
    });
 })
 .post("/", async(ctx) => {
     await ctx.render("a", {
       mary:"yes"
     });
     $(".box").addClass("red");
 })
```

When I submit the form, and the `div` with class `box` should have `red`, but now it doesn't, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, here is typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the separation between server side code and front end code. The backend has no access to the DOM because its only purpose is to serve data (HTML, JS, etc.) to the client.

Your line `$("box").addClass("red");` should therefore be moved to the EJS template.

a.js:

```
 // a.js
 .post("/", async(ctx) => {
     await ctx.render("a", {
       mary:"yes", boxClass: "red"
     });
 })
```

a.ejs:

```
// a.ejs
<form action="/" method="post">
    <div class="box <%=boxClass?(boxClass):""%>"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <%=mary%>
</form>
```